# How to prevent JEditorPane from resizing

Tags: java, swing

I have a JEditorPane inside of a JScrollPane. I call `setHorizontallyResizable(false)` on both of them, and yet when I add HTML text to the JEditorPane that extends further than the border, the JEditorPane and JScrollPane get bigger.

What I want is the JScrollPane to get horizontal scroll bars instead of resizing. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Please provide a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to override following method to return false:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()

Also you can try to fix the size of jscrollpane by using appropriate layout manager. For example if you use box layout and set the maximum size to be same as the preferred size then layout manager won't increase the size of component.